# Aggregrate the variable from timestamp on bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am planning to calculate the most frequency part_of_day for each of the user. In this case, firstly, I encoded timestamp with part_of_day, then aggregrate with the most frequency part_of_day. I use the ARRAY_AGG to calculate the mode (). However, I’m not sure how to deal with timestamp with the ARRAY_AGG, because there is error, so my code structure might be wrong

```
SELECT  User_ID, time,
ARRAY_AGG(Time ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] part_of_day,

case
  when  time BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '12:00:00' 
  then  "morning"
  when  time < '04:00:00' OR time > '20:00:00' 
  then  "night" 
end AS part_of_day 

FROM (
      SELECT User_ID, 
        TIME_TRUNC(TIME(Request_Timestamp), SECOND) AS Time
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
```

Error received:

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "COUNT" at [19:9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you did not share any sample data, I was able to identify some issues within your code.

I have used some sample data I created based in the formats and functions you used in your code to keep consistency. Below is the code, without any errors:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT 98 as User_ID,DATETIME "2008-12-25 05:30:00.000000" AS Request_Timestamp, "something!" AS channel UNION ALL
SELECT 99 as User_ID,DATETIME "2008-12-25 22:30:00.000000" AS Request_Timestamp, "something!" AS channel
)
SELECT  User_ID, time,
ARRAY_AGG(Time ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] part_of_day1,

case
  when  time BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '12:00:00' 
  then  "morning"
  when  time < '04:00:00' OR time > '20:00:00' 
  then  "night" 
end AS part_of_day 

FROM (
      SELECT User_ID,
        TIME_TRUNC(TIME(Request_Timestamp), SECOND) AS time,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM data
   GROUP BY User_ID, Channel, Request_Timestamp
   #order by Request_Timestamp

    )
    GROUP BY User_ID, Time;
```

First, notice that I have changed the column's name in your `ARRAY_AGG()` method, it had to be done because it would cause the error *"Duplicate column name"*. Second, after your `TIME_TRUNC()` function, it was missing a comma so you could select `COUNT(*)`. Then, within your `GROUP BY`, you needed to group `Request_Timestamp` as well because it wasn't aggregated nor grouped. Lastly, in your last GROUP BY, you needed to aggregate or group `time`. Thus, after theses corrections, your code will execute without any errors.

*Note: the `Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "COUNT" at [19:9]` error you experienced is due to the missing comma. The others would be shown after correcting this one.*

Comment: Can you explain more on the UNION line. (SELECT 98 as User_ID,DATETIME "2008-12-25 05:30:00.000000"). Do you specify the timestamp you want to query?

Comment: Everything inside the WITH statement is my sample data ( which I called data), I just joined two lines of data I created, that is why I used UNION ALL. Notice that I used `data` in my FROM statement because it was defined within the WITH. Thus, in your code you do not need to use the sample data part of my code. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most frequent part of each day, you need to use the day part in the aggregation:

```
SELECT User_ID,
       ARRAY_AGG(part_of_day ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] part_of_day
FROM (SELECT User_ID, 
             (case when time BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '12:00:00' then 'morning'
                   when time < '04:00:00' OR time > '20:00:00' then 'night'
              end) AS part_of_day 
             COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM cognitivebot2.chitchaxETL.conversations 
      GROUP BY User_ID, part_of_day
     ) u
GROUP BY User_ID;
```

Obviously, if you want the channel as well, then you need to include that in the queries.